# in odoo16, how to use owl get a field value?

Tags: odoo

my odoo module named: "items", I placed a button in items_views.xml file, want to get a field value from the form view after click this button,  like:
`<button onclick="checkvalue()" type="object" string="printvalue"/>`
then I created js file in items/static/js/item.js

```
const { Component, useState, mount, xml } = owl;
odoo.define('items', function (require) {
   'use strict';
   function checkvalue() {
        var v = .... (how to write to get the field element here?)
        console.log(v);   
   }
   return {
       checkvalue: checkvalue,
   };
});
```

I have two questions,1, how to write code to get the field element, 2, above code totally wrong, but I don't know how to change it to have it work,
thanks advanced.